# ViewModel property sort of fatal with VMDisconnectedException

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

**EDIT 2**: If you're looking for an answer to a similar problem, check Stuart's answer and my comments on it.

**EDIT**: I am actually getting a `Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException`. I also recently installed Windows 8.1 and Resharper (though Resharper is suspended now).

When I access a very simple list property of my view model in my MVVMCross Xamarin iOS application, the program fails. It doesn't quit most of the time: it acts like it's running. The simulator has a black screen and there is no exception. If I breakpoint on `if (messagesViewModel != null) source.ItemsSource = messagesViewModel.Messages;` and then type `messagesViewModel.Messages` into the Immediate Window, everything stops, so I can tell it is failing at this line. If instead I "step over", it never moves to the next line.

I was having similar behavior when I was toggling this code in the `MvxTableViewSource`:

```
public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
{
    return 1;
}
```

My view model looks like this:

```
public class MessagesViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private List<BaseMessage> _messages = null;

    public List<BaseMessage> Messages
    {
        get
        {
            return _messages; //yes, I know I'm returning null
                              //I wasn't at first.
        }
    }

    public MessagesViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

This is my ViewDIdLoad on the MvxTableViewController:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var source = new MessagesTableViewSource(TableView);
    //was binding here, removed it for debug purposes

    //failure on second line here
    var messagesViewModel = ViewModel as MessagesViewModel;
    if (messagesViewModel != null) source.ItemsSource = messagesViewModel.Messages;

    TableView.Source = source;
    TableView.ReloadData();
}
```

Some initialization code:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public App()
    {
        var appStart = new MvxAppStart<MessagesViewModel>();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(appStart);
    }
}

public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    //empty functions removed.

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var presenter = new MvxTouchViewPresenter(this, Window);

        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect whatever the error is, it isn't in any of the code you have posted.

I just created a simple ViewModel:

```
public class FirstViewModel 
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private List<string> _items = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three"};
    public List<string> Items 
    {   
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); }
    }
}
```

And a simple View:

```
[Register("FirstView")]
public class FirstView : MvxTableViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // ios7 layout
        if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
           EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;

        var firstViewModel = ViewModel as FirstViewModel;
        var source = new MessagesTableViewSource(TableView);
        source.ItemsSource = firstViewModel.Items;
        TableView.Source = source;
    }

    public class MessagesTableViewSource : MvxTableViewSource
    {
        public MessagesTableViewSource(UITableView tableView) : base(tableView)
        {
            tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MessagesCell), new NSString("MessagesCell"));
        }

        protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            return tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MessagesCell");
        }
    }

    public class MessagesCell : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        public MessagesCell(IntPtr handle)
            : base(handle)
        {
            var txt = new UILabel(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 44));
            Add(txt);
            this.DelayBind(() =>
                {
                    this.CreateBinding(txt).Apply();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And this code runs fine...

---

I wouldn't completely trust the integration of Xamarin.iOS with the Immediate window - it is better now than it used to be, but I've seen several problems with it before.

Some things to possibly check:

- does the above code work for you?

  - if it does, then what's in your `BaseMessage` and `MessagesTableViewSource` classes - perhaps they are causing the problem?
- can you use `Mvx.Trace("The list is {0}", messagesViewModel.Messages ?? "-null")` to view the list? Can you use trace within the ViewModel property `get` - is it being called? Can you use trace within the ViewModel constructor?
- are all your assemblies building against the same versions of things? Are all your assemblies definitely rebuilt? (Check "Build|Configuration Manager")- what version of Xamarin.iOS are you running in VS and in the Mac?

Comment: I'll start to look into the code you posted. Thanks. In the meantime, tracing won't work because it hangs up if I access the Messages property. It will just hang up on the trace line. I'm on the alpha version of Xamarin on both, though Xamarin won't run and neither will its updater after I switched channels on Windows. I'm using VS. That version is 1.4.2 for iOS and 4.8.03015 for Android. The iOS Xamarin version on my Mac is 7.0.2.7... That seems a bit off.

Comment: Looking at your code, it may be that I'm not registering the view.

Comment: It runs now. Thank you! The only thing I had to change was moving `[Register("MessagesView")]` to the cs file instead of the designer.cs file.